# Can't Execute Any Command After Switch Set in PHP

Tags: php, switch-statement

let's say I have a switch set

```
switch(telco) {
    CASE "TELKOMSEL":
        require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/libs/functions/InjectMT_Telkomsel.php');
        InjectMe($service, $reply, $mt_type, $service, $mtsid);
        break;
    CASE "INDOSAT":
        require($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/libs/functions/InjectMT_Indosat.php');
        InjectMe($service, $reply, $mt_type, $service, $mtsid);
        break;
    default:
        print "undefined carrier";
}
```

Somehow other PHP function after this switch is not executed. Is this switch behaviour or something I forget?

Comment: Have you tried removing everything inside the cases and just echoing something instead?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function inside the case fail to insert to DB. Already fixed it and now it works. Thanks for the clue @FirstOne